# What is TKey in System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<TSource,TKey>>?

Tags: c#, linq, expression

I'm trying to store expressions required by Linq `OrderBy` clauses in data structures, so I can just go `query = query.OrderBy(MySortExpression);`

`OrderBy` takes `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<TSource,TKey>>` as a parameter.  `TSource` is the entity type you are sorting on, but what type is `TKey` supposed to be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`TKey` is a generic type argument denoting the type of the expression on which you sort. For example, if you sort strings by length, `TSource` will be `string`, and `TKey` will be `int`, as in the code below:

```
string [] myStrings = new[] {"quick", "brown", "fox", "jumps"};
var ordered = myStrings.OrderBy(s => s.Length);
```

Answer (score 3):

TKey is the type of the return type of the expression. For instance:

```
users.OrderBy(user => user.Name);
```

As Name is string, the type will be `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<User,string>>`

Answer (score 2):

The `TKey` is not bound to a specific type. Usually it is a projection of a property to a primitive type to enable sorting.

Assuming a `Person` with a `BirthYear` property you would select

```
 persons.OrderBy(p => p.BirthYear);
```